# Date.parse() behaving inconsistently

Tags: javascript, parsing, datetime, web-scraping

I'm currently using node to make a site that displays the number of days until Adventure Time's next episode airs. The approach for MVP was to scrape the [AT episodes wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Adventure_Time_episodes) for dates and show whichever comes soonest after present day.

Right now when I try to use Date.parse() on the text from the 6th column, only a specific format works. This makes plenty of sense to me, however I find that sometimes the parsing works and sometimes it doesn't on what *appear* to be strings formatted exactly the same. I'll explain below the following code which shows the scrape -> parse:

```
router.get('/adventure', function(req, res) {
    var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Adventure_Time_episodes';

    request(url, function(error, response, html){
        if(!error){
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);

            $('.vevent > td:nth-child(6)').filter(function(){
                var rough = $(this).text(),
                    data;
                console.log('rough '+ JSON.stringify(rough));
                // var data = (rough.indexOf('(') == -1)? rough : rough.split('(')[0].slice(0,-1)
                if (rough.indexOf('(') > 0) {
                    data = rough.split('(')[0].slice(0,-1);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    console.log(Date.parse(data));
                } else {
                    data = rough
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    console.log(Date.parse(data));
                }
                console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(data));
                if (data == 'October 28, 2014') {
                    res.json({woof:data})
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**If you feel impelled to point out something unrelated to Date.parse(), please feel free! I'm wet behind the ears and hungry to learn.*

I use JSON.stringify() in an attempt to expose any special characters but they don't seem to be the problem. Below is the log from the server:

```
rough "July 11, 2011"
"July 11, 2011"
1310356800000
string
rough "July 18, 2011"
"July 18, 2011"
1310961600000
string
...
rough "October 15, 2012 (2012-10-15)"
"October 15, 2012"
NaN
string
rough "October 22, 2012 (October 22, 2012)"
"October 22, 2012"
1350878400000
string
rough "November 12, 2012 (2012-11-12)"
"November 12, 2012"
NaN
string
...
rough "\nTBA\n"
"\nTBA\n"
NaN
```

So the thing that really weirds me out is that the information that's supposedly being cut off effects whether or not it's properly parsed. Yes, I'm also confused by their inconsistent date formatting haha

Has anybody else encountered something like this? Am I just completely missing something? Thanks for your time!

Comment: `JSON.stringify(foo)` is not the same as `foo`, try logging `foo` directly when you want to debug it. Also if you want to log the types it might be cleaner to use something like this `function log(x) {console.log(typeof x, x);}` then `log('hello');` gives you both on one line

Comment: I like that! I've actually exhausted all the permutations of w/ and w/o `JSON.stringify()` with no success but I'm gonna start using that super log

Comment: So I wouldn't say this _solved_ the problem but I have been able to parse dates properly using the [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) external library.